# WPF-Caliburn.Micro-NLog handle exception on App Domain

Tags: wpf, exception, appdomain, nlog, caliburn.micro

Hi I try log expcetion on App Domain with NLog. It is WPF app with Caliburn Micro.

In MEF bootstraper I have this code:

```
static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLog(typeof(NLogLogger));

#region Constructors

    public MefBootStrapper()
        : base()
    {
        _msgBox = new MessageBoxes();
        _doHandle = true;
    }

    static MefBootStrapper()
    {
        LogManager.GetLog = type => new NLogLogger(type);
    }


#endregion


#region Exception handling on App Domain

protected override void OnUnhandledException(object sender, 
    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    if (_doHandle)
    {
        Log.Error(e.Exception.InnerException);
        _msgBox.ShowException(e.Exception.InnerException);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Log.Error(e.Exception.InnerException);
        _msgBox.ShowException(e.Exception);
        e.Handled = false;
    }

}

#endregion
```

When I run app and throw exception from view modle class it show message box that is ok but exception is not logged to file.

I try log exception in view model calls:

something like this:                  Log.Error(new Exception("4"));

This work, but If i try log exception in OnUnhandleException method it doesnt wokr. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the static field `Log` gets initialized before your static constructor runs see ([Static field initialization)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645758%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). So you will have your `Log` field with the default Caliburn Nulloger initialized instead of your NLogLogger. You should move the Log field initialization into your static constructor.

```
private static readonly ILog Log;

static MefBootStrapper()
{
    LogManager.GetLog = type => new NLogLogger(type);
    Log = LogManager.GetLog(typeof(NLogLogger));
}
```

Comment: @John do you need any more help with this question? :-)